# How to define multiple functions in single function declaration?

Tags: python, function

In Fortran you can do something like this:

```
#:for DTYPE, NAME in [('real','ssygvd'), ('dble', 'dsygvd'), ('cmplx', 'chegvd')]

  subroutine ${DTYPE}$_something_${NAME}$(args)
  [some commands]
  end subroutine ${DTYPE}$_something_${NAME}$
```

Can something like this be done in Python?

I want to write a function like this for float, int and str.

```
def get_int_tuple(value):
   try:
       values = [int(i) for i in value.split(',')]
       assert len(values) in range(1,4)
   except (ValueError, AssertionError):
       raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
           'Provide a CSV list of 1 up to 3 integers'
       )

   # return our value as is if there is only one
   if len(values) == 1:
       return tuple(np.array(values))

   # if there are three - return a range
   return tuple(np.arange(*values))
```

Which I will then pass to the parser:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--kernel",
    type=get_str_tuple,
    help="SVM kernel. Options: 'linear', 'poly', 'rbf' (default=rbf)"
)

parser.add_argument(
    '--c',
    type=get_float_tuple,
    help="C (hyper)parameter of 'rbf' kernel (default=0.05)."
)

parser.add_argument(
    '--degree',
    type=get_int_tuple,
    help="Degree of the 'poly' kernel. (default=3)."
)
```

Comment: To do what?[​](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71605444)

Comment: To avoid having to define exactly same function for different types

Comment: Python can handle multiple types in the same function. There is no need for having multiple functions.

Comment: If you describe what your code is supposed to do, someone who knows about Python can probably tell you how to do it. Otherwise you would need someone who understands enough of both languages to answer.

Comment: I want to define 4 different datatypes that I will pass to my parser. Don't close the question.... this is a completely valid question...

Comment: Do function names have some effect on the function in Fortran? Python is dynamically typed, so it's not clear why you would need multiple identical functions.

Comment: Ok I will write everything I need to do then

Comment: Done, post has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types themselves are first-class objects, so you can pass them as arguments to a single function.

First, define a function that defines the common function, closing over the desired type.

```
def make_type(type_, type_name):
    def get_tuple(value):
       try:
           values = [type_(i) for i in value.split(',')]
           assert len(values) in range(1,4)
       except (ValueError, AssertionError):
           raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
               f'Provide a CSV list of 1 or 3 {type_name}'
           )
    
       # return our value as is if there is only one
       if len(values) == 1:
           return tuple(np.array(values))
    
       # if there are three - return a range
       return tuple(np.arange(*values))
    return get_tuple
```

Then use `make_type` to create the necessary argument for the `type` argument to `add_argument.

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--kernel",
    type=make_type(str, "strings"),
    help="SVM kernel. Options: 'linear', 'poly', 'rbf' (default=rbf)"
)

parser.add_argument(
    '--c',
    type=make_type(float, "floating-point values"),
    help="C (hyper)parameter of 'rbf' kernel (default=0.05)."
)

parser.add_argument(
    '--degree',
    type=make_tuple(int, "integers"),
    help="Degree of the 'poly' kernel. (default=3)."
)
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner! Just one question why is type_name within curly braces? I guess I'm not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: It's an f-string (introduced in Python 3.6); the value of the variable is incorporated into the string. It's basically a shortcut for `'... {}'.format(type_name)`. The only purpose of the `type_name` parameter is to customize the exception raised for the actual type in a way that can't be derived from the type itself.